# How to use a default app/policies/application_policy.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

When ever I create a new scaffold I'd like to use it the default pundit config which is available in `app/policies/application_policy.rb`. Without creating one `model_name_policy.rb` I always get `unable to find policy` errors.

How can I use the defaults when I didn't setup rules for a specific model?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I am in the same situation, and am curious about your final approach..

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is probably to rescue from the `Pundit::NotDefinedError` raised by `Pundit::PolicyFinder#policy!`.

Given your default policy:

```
# app/policies/application_policy.rb:
ApplicationPolicy = Struct.new :user, :record do
  def index?
    true
  end

  def show?
    true
  end

  # ... other sensible defaults

end
```

Assuming you are using this in a Rails controller:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb:
class ApplicationController
  include Pundit

  # ...

  private

  def policy(record)
    super
  rescue Pundit::NotDefinedError
    ApplicationPolicy.new pundit_user, record
  end
end
```

Disclaimer:  I should also state that creating implicit default policies [is generally frowned upon](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/issues/321).  Except in the simplest cases or with the most pessimistic defaults (all false), it is all too easy for an overly permissive policy to slip through.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way without create a policy for each model, but you can create a policy that inherits from your application policy.  Your `ApplicationPolicy` might look something like this:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  def index?
    true
  end

  def show?
    true
  end

  ... More actions ...
end
```

When you set up a new scaffold, simply add a blank policy that inherits from your application policy:

```
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

end
```

The actions will inherit from `ApplicationPolicy`.  If needed you can always override the defaults:

```
classUserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  show?
    @user.admin == true ? true : false
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I'm searching for a true default where I don't have to create a policy file for a new class.

Answer (score 1):

I use pundit 2.1.0

`authorize` or `policy_scope` method use `PolicyFinder` to find policy classes, so it is useless to override `policy` method only if you use `authorize` or `policy_scope` to do the thing. I use the following way to set a default policy in my application:

```
Pundit::PolicyFinder.class_eval do
  def policy
    klass = find(object)
    (klass.is_a?(String) ? klass.safe_constantize : klass) || DefaultPolicy # set a default policy
  end
end
```

Maybe it is not the best method(it modifies the method in the original lib brutally and violates the design of the lib), but it is enough for me.

May it helps!